# Add Buttons & stuff to supportMapFragment with no XML

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, supportmapfragment

I have supportMapFragment inside a fragment pager.

I can add marks, modify them, and other cool things, but I can't figure out how to add the simple button for geolocation (to point to my position on user's pleasure).

I have no XML for it, or I should have a fragment (supportmapfragment) inside a fragment (my custom layout) inside a pager. I don't think I can.. So presumably I have to add them via code at onCreate method.

Have you any advice or alternatives? Thanks

PS: However I used the pager for the cool slide it gaves me for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "My location" button by adding these lines:

```
UiSettings uiSettings = map.getUiSettings();
uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```